# How to have an element load with the application in Ember.js

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js

I am trying to create my first ember application but I can't have a template load with the application template:

Below is a simplified version of my layout:

```
    <script type="text/x-handlebars">
     {{outlet}}
    </script>
```

How do I get the another template into the outlet section on page load?

Thanks in advance

For example if my second template is:

```
    <script type="text/x-handlebars" id="yellow">
     <p>Something</p>
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Marcio answer is correct, ember does create an implicit `index` route.

However the most important part here is that if you have, say a route like `yellow` that you want to be rendered inside the `application`'s `{{outlet}}` (instead of the implicit index template) then you need to define a `path` for that route so the correspondent named template, (in your case `yellow`) will be rendered into the `application`'s `{{outlet}}` instead of the implicit `index`:

```
App.Router.map(function() {
  this.route('yellow', {path: '/'})
});

<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="application">
  <h1>Hi</h1>
  {{outlet}}
</script>

<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="yellow">
  <h2>Welcome from yellow</h2>  
</script>
```

If you don't do this then ember will search for an `index` template to be rendered inside the outlet, and since you doesn't have one, nothing will be displayed. So again, by defining a `path` like `"/"` for your `yellow` route you instruct ember to use the `yellow` template instead of the `index`.

Of course, if you rename your `yellow` template to `index` then it will be picked up by ember and rendered inside the `application` outlet and you don't need to specify a path for the `yellow` route.

Example [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ATU4U/).

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

When you create a route like this:

```
App.Router.map(function() {
  this.route('yellow')
});
```

and a transition is performed to `yellow` route. 
For example, via `{{#link-to 'yellow'}}Yellow{{/link-to}} or changing the url to`http://www.yourhost.com#/yellow`

A handlebar template is appended in the dom, with the same name like the route:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" id="yellow">
  <p>Something</p>
</script>
```

By default ember create a `route('index')` in your router mapping, like this:

```
App.Router.map(function() {
  this.route('yellow')
  // this.route('index', { path: '/' })
});
```

So creating a index template will work

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" id="index">
 Welcome
</script>
```

When the user navigate to the url `http://www.yourhost.com`, he will see `Welcome`.

See this demo http://jsfiddle.net/marciojunior/Db49u/